# How can I store data locally with angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am looking at an angularjs 1.5 application that has a lot of ajax requests. To minimize the amount of requests to the server , I was thinking of using redux for ng1 but this looks like there is a lot of boilerplate that needs to be written first. I could not find any alternatives, what would be another way of storing jsondata locally available globally in your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different ways to store data in this case, and you have to choose depending on the features you want. The most common ones are [`localStorage`, `sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage), cookies, or just in-memory (like [$cacheFactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory)). There's also sqlite and the browser http cache (which would just be for http requests, and is based on headers).

There are also many different angular libraries/packages that have abstractions of these storage mechanisms on github, npm, bower, etc that you can find by just googling.